# Getting data from database to set dynamic routes in getStaticMap method Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, next.js

In Next.js we have a feature of dynamic routing configuration on getStaticPaths method. I need to fetch the data from database based on that data, I need to set dynamic routes. But when ever I try to make a database call, I am getting an error mentioned below.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect('connection string');
    const dataBase = client.db();
    const collections = dataBase.collection('table name');
    let result = await collections .find({}, { id: 1 }).toArray();
    client.close();
    let paths = result.map((data) => ({
        params: { id: data.id.toString() }
    }));
    console.log(paths);
    return {
        fallback: false,
        paths: paths
    };
}
```

error that I can see,

```
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:7:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error indicates that you're trying to run MongoDB on the client-side, where the `dns` module doesn't exist. Are you sure the error is coming from that `getStaticPaths` function? Are you using the MongoDB client somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks your help. This issue was occurring  because  to use getStaticPaths method, we need to define getStatePaths method. I had not defined this getStaticPath method , thats why I was facing this issue

Comment: Check `import` statements.  If you import a file that does NOT run (ie. comment out the function invocation), then this error will throw.  Comment out the import to resolve.